# Eclipse Java launch configuration file path

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration-files

I'm looking for a file where Eclipse stores its launch configurations. I'm doing some Java development in Ubuntu.

One of the executables i'm developing requires an output from another executable as a argument to it. So say, the output of 'B' needs to be passed as a commandline argument to 'A'. In the Eclipse, I don't want to manually change the "Run Configuration" every time. Where does Eclipse store these configurations esp the arguments?

I found a "eclipseArguments.txt" in the extras folder of the project but this isn't the same as the arguments I'm passing into the Run Configurations. The ".project" file doesn't contain it either. I'm confused.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in Debug config. Once I run module, in the debug window I can right click an go to Properties or some similar option and then there is a full path with all arguments.

Comment: Luke's answer, below, is so much better.

Answer (score 125):

You can find the configuration files in :

> <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches

There should be a `*.launch` file for every configuration you have in this workspace stored there.

Comment: You have to restart the eclipse to reflect the changes done, like a delete or modification.

Comment: This is possibly the 10th time I've read this answer in the past few years!

Comment: @HDave Make that 11

Answer (score 14):

I'm not certain where Eclipse stores the 'local' run configurations (likely somewhere under the workspace .metadata directory), but under the 'common' tab of the Run Configurations dialog, there's an option to save it as a 'Shared file' within a project, in which case it will show up in your project directory.

Comment: I really like this answer b/c you can check your launches into version control.  Also don't forget to use base directory `${workspace_loc}/myproject` so that other people on the project can run in a different workspace.