# Update multiple eclipse run configuration user classpath setting

Tags: eclipse, junit, classpath

Background:
ProjectA is an Eclipse 4.2.1 java project with numerous junit 4 test classes. Each junit test is run individually at times and therefore has a corresponding run configuration.  Each run configuration specifies a configuration folder from ProjectB as a user class path entry.

```
ProjectA
  test
    classATest.java (run configuration user class path entry -> ProjectB/config)
    classBtest.java (run configuration user class path entry -> ProjectB/config)
    ...
ProjectB
  config *deleted*
ProjectC
  config *created*
```

Question:
If the configuration folder is moved from ProjectB to ProjectC, is there a way to perform a mass update of all the junit run configurations with a new user class path entry.

Constraints:
Maintaining a copy of the configuration folder and contents in ProjectA is not desirable because it is frequently updated.  Updating each run configuration by hand is not desirable.  Adding the junit test classes to a junit suite and having a single run configuration would possibly work, but in order to run an individual test I would need to run the suite, kill it, and run the individual test from the junit window.

Attempted:
I was unable to find a way to perform this type of update through the eclipse GUI. Maybe manipulating the eclipse files directly would work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094786/eclipse-java-launch-configuration-file-path), eclipse stores run configurations in :

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/.org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

So, using a find/replace function in a text editor or linux test manipulation programs it should be trivial to refactor the run configurations with new user class path entries.