# Eclipse fails to launch (RSEUIStartup)

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello all :) Just posting here to know if any of you have encountered this problem before:

Eclipse fails to launch, here is the .metadata/.log file from the workspace: http://pastebin.com/BeUwASQ4

It happened after the UI began malfunctioning after a line of length 1 500 000 got printed to the console (which I had configured to roll over 800 000 bytes, from the 100 000 default)

I think the key error in the log file is at the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plugin startup (line 42: `RSEUIStartup`)

IMHO the UI fails to launch because it can't handle the console again. Do you guys know how to reset the UI display from outside eclipse?

EDIT: Problem solved, thanks to Aaron! I was beginning to panic after a new install of eclipse was also crashing. I also used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094786/eclipse-java-launch-configuration-file-path) for restoring the launch configurations I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which plugin causes most problems here but when Eclipse fails to launch, you should:

1. Enable the console and debugging. Start Eclipse with `-console -consoleLog -debug`
2. Make sure Eclipse uses `java` and not `javaw` to start. Otherwise, you won't see the output.
3. To tell Eclipse what you want to debug, create a file `.options` in the same folder as `eclipse.ini`. Look for `.options` files in all the plugins to see what options you can put in this file. [Here is the .options file for the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.runtime.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.options).

That can help to narrow down the issue. But often, some file in the `.metadata` directory has been corrupted and Eclipse has no support for identifying these files.

If that's the case, you need to clean this directory. [Follow these instructions](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/) to make it work again with the least amount of hazzle.