# JavaFX files break when I upload them to Github

Tags: git, eclipse, github, javafx

I work with Eclipse, and I have my Java projects on my GitHub. That all worked fine until I started working with JavaFX. I installed JavaFX via "Install New Software," and I added the necessary SDKs. When I pull a JavaFX project from my GitHub and try to run it, it always fails:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.Main
```

I think I've also seen some other error messages, but I'm not sure anymore after all the trying I did.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a solution?

I checked the dependencies and the .classpath and .project files.

Comment: You most probably did not upload the necessary [Eclipse configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5094786/17627866) to Github.

Comment: *'I installed JavaFX via "Install New Software,"'* This doesn't really make sense. The "install new software" option in Eclipse, if I remember correctly, is to install new Eclipse plugins, not to use additional libraries in your project. Follow the standard instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ to use JavaFX in Eclipse.